# $_REQUEST get difference value

Tags: php, echo, isset

I have a page that contain a form using method "GET". When I submit it, the value pass to the next page is for example `http://localhost/land_by_province.php?province_id=14` but when I use `echo isset($_REQUEST['province_id']);` I always get '1'.

Even I the value of province_id have changed by `$_REQUEST['province_id']` always return '1'.

Why it is like that?

Answer (score 3):

`isset()` returns a boolean value, not the value of the variable. Since that variables is set you get a 1 which is what you gert when you output boolean TRUE in PHP.

So, you jst want to echo out the variables contents without using `isset()`.

```
echo $_REQUEST['province_id'];
```

FYI, it is always safer to use `$_GET` over `$_REQUEST`.

Answer (score 0):

ISSET

ISSET checks the variable to see if it has been set, in other words, it checks to see if the variable is any value except NULL or not assigned a value. ISSET returns TRUE if the variable exists and has a value other than NULL. That means variables assigned a " ", 0, "0", or FALSE are set, and therefore are TRUE for ISSET

you have to

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['province_id']))  //if value set it return 1 i.e true
 {
   echo $_REQUEST['province_id'];
 }
 else
  {
    echo "Not Set";
  }
```